# Python returns the middle path of neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j

I am try to return the full path of neo4j,but it can only return start node and end node in python which return full path in neo4j.

My python code is:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase,basic_auth

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("", ""))

session = driver.session()

paths = session.run('''PROFILE
                   with ['aaa''bbb''ccc''ddd''eee'] as value_list
                   match (n:Node) where n.value in value_list
                       with collect(n) as result
                       unwind result as source
                       unwind result as target
                   match paths = shortestpath((source)-[*0..2]-(target)) where source<>target
                       with paths limit 200
                       return paths''')

for record in paths:
    print(",".join("%s:%s"%(key,record[key]) for key in record.keys()))

session.close()
```

The path return in neo4j is:

```
"paths"                                                             
[{"value":"aaa"},{"value":"ab_relation"},{"value":"bbb"},"value":"bbb"},{"value":"bc_relation"},{"value":"ccc"}] 
[{"value":"aaa"},{"value":"ad_relation"},{"value":"ddd"},"value":"ddd"},{"value":"de_relation"},{"value":"eee"}]
```

but return in python:

```
paths:<Path start=<Node id=9650694 labels={'Node'} properties={'value': 'aaa'}> end=<Node id=23038409 labels={'Node'} properties={'value': 'ccc'}> size=2>
paths:<Path start=<Node id=9650694 labels={'Node'} properties={'value': 'aaa'}> end=<Node id=9011159 labels={'Node'} properties={'value': 'eee'}> size=2>
```

How can I have the full path rather than only start node and end node?

Answer (score 0):

This can return the full path!!!

```
for record in paths:
    #print(record)
    relationships = record["path"].relationships
    nodes = record["path"].nodes
    path = ""
    for i in (range(len(relationships))):
        path += "{0}-[{1}]->".format(nodes[i]["value"], relationships[i]["value"])
    path += nodes[-1]["value"]
    wt.write(path+'\n')
```

reference：[explain this question here](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/types/graph.html?highlight=relationships#neo4j.types.graph.Relationship)